# POSITION ORDERING , MIN AND MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like so.

Table A

> [Job Lot] [Job ID] [Child Job ID]   [Time Completed]   [Order of Jobs Done]  [Min] [Max] [AVG]
>
> 1       11        100                 10                 Pos1
>
> 1       11        101                 20                 Pos 2
>
> 1       11        103                 30                 Pos 3
>
> 2       12        101                 30                 Pos 1
>
> 2       12        105                 10                 Pos 3

Each Child Job ID represents a delivery to a particular site like New York, Washington or LA each week.

So I need to work work out say for Child ID 10 what is the average postion . I see in JOB ID 11 it has Child Job ID 10 in POS 1 and in JOB ID 12 it is in POS 2, so the min is POS1 , the max is POS3, and the average is POS 2.

How can I calculate the min, max and average for all the CHILD JOB IDs in sql ?

Comment: Can you properly format your data?

Comment: So I have to calculate the min, max and avg columns based on this logic which is in the text above.

Comment: and the current format is unreadable

Comment: How can you put a table in properly ? Apologies working on this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store just the POS number in the field, then the SQL is simple.

```
Select CHILD_JOB_ID, MIN(POS), MAX(POS), AVG(POS)
from table-name
group by CHILD_JOB_ID
```

If the POS field has a string with a 'POS ' prefix, then you might get the results from

```
Select CHILD_JOB_ID,
       MIN(SUBSTRING(POS, 5, LEN(POS)),
       MAX(SUBSTRING(POS, 5, LEN(POS)),
       AVG(SUBSTRING(POS, 5, LEN(POS))
from table-name
group by CHILD_JOB_ID
```

Comment: There is no values in the min, max and avg columns . Only the Completed order of Jobs is populated in this table .

Comment: Sorry this does not work. Apologies maybe I was very clear with the question . Hope it is clearer now.